# Vim commands :Explore :Sexplore :Hexplore doesn't work in cygwin

Tags: vim, cygwin

3.3 in cywing 2.721, the installation was made using cywing, every thing works but when I try to use the following command.

```
:Explore
```

vim said `E492: Not an editor command`

also neither `:Sexplore` or `:Hexplore` works.

is there any way to activate this functionality?

This is in machine with windows xp.

Answer (score 5):

Well I solved reading the

`:help usr_01.txt`

It said that is necessary to run this command `!cp -i $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim ~/.vimrc` inside vim, it just copy a .vimrc to home user.

I close and opened vim and :Explore, Hexplore, Vexplore worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well. Since it's a fresh install of Vim you don't have a .vimrc (or _vimrc on Windows). A vimrc is Vim's configuration file, and once you have one Vim will no longer try to be compatible with Vi (usually what you want).

So all you have to do is create a vimrc file and you should be ready to `:Explore` all you want. Below are locations you can put your vimrc file, and the filename to use for it. (depending on your system)

```
    Unix/Linux/OSX: $HOME/.vimrc or $HOME/.vim/vimrc

    MS-Windows: $HOME/_vimrc, $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc
            or $VIM/_vimrc
```

sources:
* [:help 'compatible'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27compatible%27)
* [:help 'vimrc'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc)

I also recommend following `atomsfat's` answer as well to give you a simple vimrc to start out with.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands are provided by the `netrw` plugin.  Check `:scriptnames` to see if that plugin is loaded.

Comment: yes it have that:  gzip.vim, netrwPlugin.vim, spellfile.vim,tohtml.vim, zipPlugin.vim, getscriptPlugin.vim  matchparen.vim, rrhelper.vim, tarPlugin.vim, vimballPlugin.vim